# TCGA2STAT R package does not work in windows: How to resolve?

Tags: r, linux, windows, tar

As mentioned in the title, `TCGA2STAT R package` does not work in windows.
(which for downloading compressed TCGA data from broad institute server)

When I run the `getTCGA` function, following error occurres:

> Error: TAR is not installed in the system. Data unzip failed.

I tried to install cygwin, Rtools, 7zip, etc based on internet searching results, but none of them worked.

I do not know if Windows itself is a problem.

Is there any solution other than running on Linux?

Thank you in advance.

BH Kim

Comment: Did you add the `7zip/bin` folder to the system variables?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work. Is tar-unpack program other than 7zip helpful?

Comment: I am using the [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). In the /bin folder you will find a `zip.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Rtools` installed, you might just need to explicitly set the path to your `Rtools` installation, for example

```
Sys.setenv(R_GZIPCMD ="C:\\Rtools\\bin\\gzip")
Sys.setenv(TAR ="C:\\Rtools\\bin\\tar")
```

It might also help to check

```
Sys.which("tar")
```

To see if there's another version of tar that might be conflicting

Comment: Thanks!! After I set the path, previous error 'TAR is not installed in the system. Data unzip failed.' disappeared, but following error still occurred :Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : 'C:\Rtools\bin' not found ; although C:\Rtools\bin is correct path;

Comment: See edit above, you may need to add the name of the command too

Comment: there's no other version of tar after checking sys.which("tar"). My command is 'getTCGA(disease = "LUSC", data.type = "RNASeq2", type = "", filter = "Y",  
        p = getOption("mc.cores", 2L), clinical = FALSE, cvars = "OS")' and entire error code is 'RNASeqV2 data will be imported! This may take some time!
Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : 'C:\Rtools\bin' not found' (not solved yet)

Comment: Try changing to `Sys.setenv(TAR ="C:\\Rtools\\bin\\tar")`

Comment: Many thanks to kind reply. Due to the limit of the comment, I answered below :). Whenever I tried your suggestion, error messages were slightly changed, but not completely finished.

Comment: Hi Byong, I will look into this more for you, but in the meantime it would be better to add the second error message in as an edit to your original question.

Comment: The second error usually occurs when the file is corrupt. However in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TCGA2STAT/vignettes/TCGA2STAT.html) it states that TCGA2STAT only supports native versions of TAR, and therefore may not work on Windows even with third-party versions. The package is also no longer [being maintained](https://rampages.us/vcucctrbioinformatics/wp-content/uploads/sites/24649/2017/07/GDC_API_Tutorial_July2017.pdf). Maybe something like [TCGAbiolinks](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/TCGAbiolinks.html) would suit your purposes?

Comment: hmm, maybe I'll find some other packages. thanks Esther!